# make_clickable - stop http:// protocol prefix displaying on website

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I'm using the make_clickable function in conjunction with Advance Custom Fields in Wordpress (see code below). If the user inputs www.website.com in the field, the following is displayed on the site http://www.website.com text. 
How can I remove both the http:// and the www. protocols and just have website.com (or at the very least remove the http:// part? Thanks, James

p.s. I checked out the Wordpress Codex - if the answer is there then it's way beyond me.

Comment: This relates to server configuration, not WordPress. Where is your site hosted?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are no filters in the make_clickable function. (I am thinking about proposing a patch with hooks for it)

So the only way you could do it is to make your own copy of the make_clickable function and _make_url_clickable_cb callback function with your own custom names.

Then change your new copy of _make_url_clickable_cb function to return what you want.
Eg. this line.

```
return $matches[1] . "<a href=\"$url\" rel=\"nofollow\">$url</a>" . $suffix;
```

Comment: Hi Topdown, that's a clear enough answer, but I went for quick global site fix and dumped the Advanced Custom Field text area. I used auto-hyperlink-url plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-hyperlink-urls/changelog/

Comment: Will get back to issue and try your answer. Thanks for the speedy reply. James

Comment: It feels like an hack, but works. Just implemented it.